# Azure Devops Releases Pre-deployment comment edit

Tags: azure-devops

I have a lot of releases and there are pre-deployment approver. Approver writes comment before approve and I want to edit old comment. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, either via the interface or via the API, the idea being that an approval for a release should be an immutable record of that event.

If you try and update an 'approved' approval via [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), you will get the relevant exception:

**Request**

```
PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/approvals/{approvalId}?api-version=5.0-preview.3

 {
  "status": "approved",
  "comments": "Change comment"
 }
```

**Response**

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Approval(s) {approvalId} are not in a pending state. Only pending approval(s) can be updated. Please refresh the release and provide pending approvals.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data",
    "typeKey": "InvalidRequestException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

If you have a situation whereby something offensive or inappropriate has been written into these comments in your organisation you could try to delete the release entirely or contact Azure DevOps support.